# Users with custom roles can't read each other's comments

Tags: comments, user-roles, capabilities

My site has a custom role ("coach") with its own set of capabilities (via `map_meta_cap` along with a few built-in roles). Each user is assigned a page on the site that they "own" and can edit (via a front-end editor).

Each page has comments (rebranded as "reviews").

This system works pretty well, except for one thing: WordPress won't return comments on pages that this user (with the "coach" role) doesn't 'own'.

I'm getting comments with `get_comments()`, and it returns exactly what I expect if I'm logged out, logged in as an administrator, or logged in as a 'coach' and viewing that coach's page. When logged in as a 'coach' and viewing another page, `get_comments()` returns an empty array.

This seems like a role/capability issue, but I'm having a hard time pinning down exactly what's happening. I've played with adding various capabilities to the coach role, but with no luck.

Here's the code I'm using to return comments:

```
$testimonials = get_comments( array(
    'post_id' => $coach_post_ID,
    'status'  => 'approve',
) );
```

Running `var_dump( $testimonials );` returns an empty array, unless I'm logged in as that 'coach', an administrator, or logged out entirely.

The coaches have all the public `read` capabilities enabled (`read` and `read_coach`) and can otherwise see all the content on other coach pages.

I'm happy to provide any information you might need to help diagnose the problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, main users have the **contributor** role and a simple sidebar comment sidebar widget was not working when logged-in! Strange. I solved it by some sql:

```
function getLatestComments ( $postid ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT * from $wpdb->comments WHERE
             comment_post_ID = $postid AND 
             comment_approved = 1 
             ORDER BY comment_ID DESC";
    return $wpdb->get_results($sql);
}
```

I used this instead of get_comments. You may modify the sql and customize as required.

Comment: Thanks cenk! I'm going to give this a try and see what happens.